# How to enable Android-14 'Accessibility' Restricted Setting?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, service, background-process

In Android 14, we utilized the 'Accessibility' service API in our application. However, this option is not available by default. After clicking "OK" on the 'Restricted Setting' dialog, we enable the necessary permissions.

The issue arises when we update the application using a side-loaded APK. Upon updating, the 'Accessibility' service API option becomes disabled, and we are required to grant the permission once more.

Is this feature introduced in Android 14, or is there any workaround to ensure that the permission remains enabled every time we update the application?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings -> Apps -> All Apps.
Click on the app for which you are getting Restricted msg or for which you want to give the accessibility access.
After clicking on the app Click on the three dots at top right corner.
Now Click on Allow Restricted Settings.
Now you can give accessibility access to your app.

Comment: In Pixel Android-14 device ask 'Accessibility' permission every time, When I update the application.

Answer (score 1):

This feature came with `Android 13`.

**Reason**

Android 13 or a more recent Android version. Android 13+ assumes that apps not distributed from curated stores are often from shady websites and could thus be malicious. That's why it is harder to grant those apps permissions.

**Solution - Suggestion**

> When you enable restricted settings, you allow apps to get access to
> sensitive info that could put your personal data at risk. We don’t
> recommend that you allow restricted settings unless you trust the app
> developer.
>
> Some legitimate apps might ask you to enable restricted settings. For
> example, an app that’s designed to support people with disabilities
> might ask you to turn on accessibility settings. With access to
> accessibility settings, the app can read content on your screen and
> interact with apps on your behalf.

1. On your Android device, open the Settings app.
2. Tap Apps.
3. Tap the app that you want to turn on a restricted setting for.
4. Tap More  and then Allow restricted settings.
5. Follow the on-screen instructions.

Comment: Once we grant the permission, after update the application. again the accessibility permission is disable.

 Is this possible to keep the permission enable after update the application?

Comment: No, unless sent to market

Comment: In Pixel Android-14 device ask 'Accessibility' permission every time, When I update the application.
 @ΓDΛ

Comment: Someone who had the same problem as you provided a solution like this. https://help.niagaralauncher.app/article/134-fix-restricted-settings